# Data type for gaussian Naive bayes classifivation using sklearn, how to clean data

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, classification

I'm trying to classify mobiles according to their features but when I apply the gaussian NB code through sklearn , I'm unable to do so because of the following error : 
the code :

```
clf = GaussianNB()
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
GaussianNB()
accuracy = clf.score(X_test,y_test)
print(accuracy)
```

error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-e9515ccc2439> in <module>()
      2 clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
      3 GaussianNB()
----> 4 accuracy = clf.score(X_test,y_test)
      5 print(accuracy)

/Users/kiran/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in score(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    347         """
    348         from .metrics import accuracy_score
--> 349         return accuracy_score(y, self.predict(X), sample_weight=sample_weight)
    350 
    351 

/Users/kiran/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.py in predict(self, X)
     63             Predicted target values for X
     64         """
---> 65         jll = self._joint_log_likelihood(X)
     66         return self.classes_[np.argmax(jll, axis=1)]
     67 

/Users/kiran/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.py in _joint_log_likelihood(self, X)
    422         check_is_fitted(self, "classes_")
    423 
--> 424         X = check_array(X)
    425         joint_log_likelihood = []
    426         for i in range(np.size(self.classes_)):

/Users/kiran/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    380                                       force_all_finite)
    381     else:
--> 382         array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
    383 
    384         if ensure_2d:

ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

My dataset has been scraped so it contains string as well as float values. It would be helpful if someone could suggest me how I can clean the data and avoid the error .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following:

```
accuracy = clf.score(X_test.astype('float'),y_test.astype('float'))
```

Comment: it still shows the same error .

Comment: Can you do print(X_test) and print(Y_test)to show us what's inside?

Comment: 'print(X_test)'

[[32 '4' 12 1]
 [8 '1' 8 0]
 [32 '3' 13 0]
 [64 '6' 16 1]
 [16 '2' 12 0]
 [16 '3' 13 0]
 [16 '2' 8 0]
 [64 '4' 16 1]
 [128 '6' 16 1]
 [8 '1' 8 0]
 [128 '6' 12 1]
 [64 '4' 12 1]
 [64 '4' 16 0]
 [128 '4' 12 1]
 [32 '4' 16 0]
 [32 nan 16 1]
 [16 nan 8 0]
 [16 nan 8 0]
 [16 '3' 13 0]
 [64 '6' 16 1]]

'print(y_test)'[1 3 2 2 3 3 3 2 2 3 3 1 2 1 2 2 3 3 3 2] I did change the nan valuse to -99999 but it still shows nan

Answer (score 1):

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float
```

I think this says it all. You need to have `float` as consistent datatype in your dataset.

To convert a `string` in python to `float`:

```
>>> a = "123.345"
>>> float(a)
>>> 123.345
>>> int(float(a))
>>> 123
```

Comment: Also, it is easier to answer a question if all the relevant information is provided in the question. You should post a snippet (a small subset) of the dataset with the question too.

Comment: Is there a way to do that to string datasets ?

Comment: I will do that ! I will edit and add the data set.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include how to convert string to float. Do check.

Comment: So is your problem fixed now?

Comment: Yes, the previous error isn't present anymore but i'm getting the following error now ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-17196cc5b873> in <module>()
----> 1 clf = GaussianNB()
      2 clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
      3 GaussianNB()
      4 ccuracy = clf.score(X_test.astype('float'),y_test.astype('float'))
      5 print(accuracy)

NameError: name 'GaussianNB' is not defined   ....... I have imported GaussianNB thoough

Comment: Have you installed sklearn on your computer?

Comment: It doesn't come pre-installed. You have to install it separately.

Comment: I installed it on conda and no longer have that error. thank you